# Was the middle finger obscene in Ancient Rome?

Tags: classical-latin, roman-culture

I was recently reading a work where I became (re)acquainted with the fact that the middle finger can be referred to as the *digitus impudicus* -- the "shameful finger" -- in Latin.

My question is whether we have **classical attestations, anecdotal or otherwise, of the middle finger having the same meaning** as it does in many cultures today.

Comment: Quite a lot of info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_finger#Classical_era

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The middle finger is mostly known from Greek comedy, but it is also mentioned in some Latin sources.

Martial's *Epigram* 28, lines 1–2:

> Rideto multum qui te, Sextille, cinaedum
>   Dixerit et digitum porrigito medium.

"Laugh at the man who calls you a faggot, Sextillus, and extend your middle finger."

Answer (score 2):

[Logeion, s.v. *impudicus*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/impudicus), gives Martial 6.70.5 which mind you isn't specified as being the middle finger. But there's an interesting and amusing commentary on that passage in an article [(CJ 47:67)](http://bit.ly/impudicus) on Roman Elementary Mathematics by J. Hilton Turner, which makes it pretty clear that it was. Elsewhere in the same article, there's a translation of a chunk of Bede in which he talks of the middle finger (clear from the context, despite no Latin original in the article) as *impudicus*.

In [Muratori (XI, part 3, p126)](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_Jj_e0Sqa0zMC/page/n131/mode/2up), in the anonymous *Liber de computo sive kalendario* attributed to Cyril of Alexandria, §138 there's another *digitus impudicus*; here too in the context of representing numbers on one's fingers.

Roger Pack, ["Catullus, Carmen V: Abacus or Finger-Counting?", AJP 77:47-51 at JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/291941) builds on another part of the Turner article, by suggesting that the Catullus poem maybe is best viewed not on an abacus with Turner, but in finger-counting, and there's a bit about the *impudicus* in his article as well.